# Convert UTF8 to ASCII using lazarus

Tags: freepascal, lazarus, utf8-decode

I am reading some strings from a text file, the problem is that the strings are UTF8 and contain characters that I wish to remove such as: Ă

An not easy solution would be for me to replace each occurence of illegal characters, but because I am lazy I want a simpler solution

So far I tried this :

```
    line := Utf8ToAnsi(line);
```

Where line is my UTF8 encoded string ... I tried eaven declaring line as UTF8String ...

Is there a viable solution in this matter? Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a sample line with expected result please ? It works fine for me. Although, you should store the result of the `Utf8ToAnsi` function call to a separate `AnsiString` type variable.

Comment: @TLama I tried that too, storing a AnsiString but still no result an example would be AbrogaȚie try to store it in a file read it and then write it again in another file..

Comment: [http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Multiplatform_Programming_Guide#Text_encoding](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Multiplatform_Programming_Guide#Text_encoding)?

Comment: @Abelisto just tried that same behaivour!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An not easy solution would be for me to replace each occurence of
> illegal characters, but because I am lazy I want a simpler solution

I developed a function that replaces each [diacritical character](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29584_01/webhelp/mdex_basicDev/src/rbdv_chars_mapping.html) occurrence to a similar ASCII character, e.g: Á -> A, Ç -> C, ã -> a, and so on. Please take a look at [this link](https://github.com/risoflora/brookfreepascal/blob/664b737f6e23a28cc5fc68f05d876848ac92fe51/plugins/rutils/src/rutils.pas#L1589).

HTH

Comment: Fixed broken links and improved English.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, just do:

```
type
  TASCIIString = type AnsiString(20127);

function UTF8ToASCII(const S: TASCIIString): string;
begin
  Result := S;
end;
```

If the original string has any characters that cannot be converted, it will be turned into a '?'. If you want to remove them, make a loop checking if each character is in the set ['0'..'9', 'A'..'Z'].